# Where is an Excel Add-In saved when programmatically adding and installing it?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

Im trying to automate adding & installing an Add-In for Excel where the Add-In is located on a shared network drive. I know from my reading around the web ([here](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment) and [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel/12432-share-excel-add-network-environment.html)) that I need to make the copy that's on the shared network drive Read-Only. And thanks to the first link I now know how I can go about making revisions, fixes, and additions to my Add-In down the road using this method of keeping the file on the shared network drive.

Now having an idea of the process, I started looking into how to automate the adding and installing of the Add-In once it's on the shared network drive. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32322408/2962937), which pointed me in the right direction of using the `Excel.AddIn` object. So, I was spending some time looking at the msdn documentation on the `AddIn Object` properties ([Installed Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841133.aspx) and [AddIn Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837792.aspx) itself), which is where I found this bit of code that adds and installs the Add-In in one line

```
AddIns.Add("generic.xll").Installed = True
```

**My question (and concern)**:

In the instructions below

[image: Instructions]

Bullet point five has me slightly concerned because I have not been able to find out through my digging around the web if using the above code snippet to add and install the Add-In will copy it to the local/user's folder (which I don't want), keep it in the shared network folder, or if it will prompt the user just like when they manually browse to add the Add-In. If it prompts them is there any way to choose for them (to always click 'No') or is there a way to choose 'No' without showing them the prompt at all? How can I use the above code and make sure that it's adding and installing the Add-In file that's on that shared network drive? Can anyone shed some light on this situation for me?

Comment: To me it is clear from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/installinganxla.aspx that when you `Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="C:\MyAddIn.xla").Installed = True` that the file is not copied anywhere but installed from whatever filename you specify.  But it would be easy to test.

Comment: Though that is one link I had not come across, it still doesn't seem to be completely clear as it mentions nothing about the prompt I described above (not even in the steps where a user manually adds the Add-In). For all I know it could by default take that file from the path and save it (a copy) in the local folder. So, I'm still looking for solid proof until I get the chance to test this on my company's network.

Comment: "...click the Browse button. This will open a familiar Open File dialog. Navigate to the folder in which you saved the XLA Add-In file, select that file, and click Open.[prompt should show here] This will install...."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. What you are looking for is the `CopyFile` argument of the `Addins.Add` method. Setting it to false is the same as replying "No" to the "Copy to Local Folder?" prompt:

[image]

And just to clarify what you already know the `Addin.Installed` property just determines whether the addin is selected in the Addins dialog. (Not tremendously clear to me when I first encountered it).